# Sum values from rows in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to add values from row['scores'].

For example, if I have 6 rows that have a value of 1 for each row .. I want to be able to echo -> value of rows = 6.

The `+=` is not working for me: I still get only the values themselves, e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 but I want the sum of it, let's say 1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28.

Thanks

```
<?php include("connect.php"); ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Score Predictions</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id = "id">

<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $home = $row['home'];
        $away = $row['away'];
    }
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $x = $_POST["test"];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (home, away, score) VALUES ('$home', '$away', '$x')");
    }
?>

<?php echo $home," - ",$away; ?>

    <form method = 'post' action = 'http://albsocial.us/test/index.php'>
        <select name = 'test'> 
            <option value = "" selected = 'selected'></option>
            <option VALUE = '1'>1</option>
            <option VALUE = 'X'>X</option>
            <option VALUE = '2'>2</option>   
        </select>
        <INPUT TYPE = 'submit' name = 'submit' />
    </form>

<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $score = $row['score'];
        if ($score == "1") {
            echo $sum += $score - 1;
        }
    }
?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: change this line: `echo $sum += $score-1 ;

`

Comment: >[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: you are overwriting the previous result `$id = $row['id'];
            $home = $row['home'];
            $away = $row['away'];` and if you want to use only one result then why not use condition in query  ? and your code is vulnerable to ___sql injection___ you need to escape all request

Comment: this `if ($score == "1"){


                    echo $sum += $score-1 ;

                    }` wont do anything it will just make `$sum` always 0

Comment: you are writing terrible code i am afraid but you need to rewrite code from scrap again after reading more ...

Comment: This is just scrap code my friend .. just a test ... of course when it goes live it will be improved

Answer (score 2):

```
$sum=0; 
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                 $id = $row['id'];
                 $score = $row['score'];

                     if ($score == "1"){

                         $sum = $sum+$score;

                     }

         }
echo $sum;
```

try this.
it sume al $score values.

Comment: The comment I was replying to has been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `if` condition and add the database value to `$sum` variable

```
$sum = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   $id = $row['id'];
   $score = $row['score'];
   $sum += (int)$score;
}   
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here, as other answers mostly fix, but to make clear:

- your `if $score == 1` doesn't seem relevant to your purpose. Did you mean `if $id == 1`, or were you just trying to ignore zeros? (anything + zero stays the same anyway, so you don't need to)
- there doesn't seem to be a reason for subtracting one in `$sum += $score-1` either
- you need to finish the adding up first, and then call `echo` once. Currently, you have an `echo` for every database row, which is why you're seeing multiple numbers output.
- if you're only displaying the sum anyway, you don't need to do this in a loop at all, just get the DB to add up for you, e.g. `SELECT SUM(score) AS total_score FROM test` or `SELECT id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM test GROUP BY id`